# Latex templates in vim

Tags: vim, latex

Is there a nice way how to add custom latex templates to vim? 
In texmaker I have shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and that while pressed writes all `\includepackage{}` I use.

Well, now I think about two approximate ways:

1. While creating new *.tex* file, I can import text from skeleton. But there is but. I have more different types of documents I write and I do not need import everything, because this way I will need to change part of text imported.
2. Define my own commands in vim. But there is also but. I do not need this commands in every type of file but only in *.tex* files and it is also more comfortable to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> instead of typing command.

Answer (score 2):

There exist

- snippet plugins where you can choose which skeleton you wish to expand explicitly. i.e. no expansion will be triggered on new files.
- template expander plugins that automatically expand on new files. Among them some plugins are able to detect the current situation or ask the user which exact skeleton shall be used.
- and some plugins that do both.

I've been maintaining a [fork of mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) for years now. It belongs to both categories. Its syntax is quite different from snipmate & co and its placeholder system is more intrusive. However unlike other solutions it permits to include dynamically (overridable) skeletons. This means you can have a `tex.template` skeleton that'll ask you (the end-user) which kind of LaTeX file you wish to create (an article, a book, slides, a new section, etc) and include the related and specialized skeleton.

If you look at the [**default** LaTeX skeleton](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/tex.template), you'll see that it asks the end-user what kind of file is being created -- that file is quite poor as I seldom write new LaTeX document, I've never taken the time to enhance it. You'll see an example of dynamic skeleton dispatching in [vim skeleton file](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/vim.template) -- the exact script type is deduced automatically this time.

Answer (score 0):

With your second option, you can restrict your <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> binding to `.tex` files.

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tex noremap <S-F1> ...
autocmd! BufLeave *.tex uncap <S-F1>
```

Comment: Eew. Just put `nnoremap <buffer> <S-F1> ....` into `$HOME/vim/syntax/tex.vim` (or put it in `autocmd FileType tex` if you don't want to move it from `.vimrc`). With `<buffer>`, there's no need for the ugly mapping and unmapping.

Comment: Cool, that's much nicer.